# Trying DATABSE.update showing errors

Tags: android, database

Brief of app: Add contacts / Edit Contacts

-`Contato.java` //Show a ListView of the contacts, when itemClicked shows a dialog of info(name/telephone) and 3Buttons (Ok/Alter/Delete) the `Alter` button sends the user to:

-`Adicionarcontato.java` with the info's to edit, but when I edit and hit the button "Salvar" (save) the error: `The application Mensagem(process com.example.mensagem) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.`

Here is the code of Contato.java of the ListView.

```
 private void ListaContatos(){      
    ListView user = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvShowContatos);
    //String = simple value ||| String[] = multiple values/columns
    String[] campos = new String[] {"nome", "telefone"};

    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    c = db.query( "contatos", campos, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    if(c.getCount() > 0) {
        while(true) {
           list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")).toString());
           if(!c.moveToNext()) break;
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    user.setAdapter(adapter);

    user.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            reg = position;
            c.moveToPosition(reg);
            String nome = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome"));
            String telefone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("telefone"));
            ShowMessage(nome, telefone);

        }
    });

}
```

And here is the code in the Adicionarcontato.java:

```
 public SQLiteDatabase db;
private String mIndex = "";
private String nomeant,foneant;
static final String userTable = "contatos";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.adicionarcontato);
    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        if(getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("reg")) mIndex = getIntent().getExtras().getString("reg");
    }
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("banco.db", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
    if(!mIndex.equals("")) {
        Cursor c = db.query(false, "contatos", (new String[] {"nome", "telefone"}), null, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToPosition(Integer.parseInt(mIndex));
        nomeant = c.getString(0);
        foneant = c.getString(1);
        EditText nome1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNome);
        EditText telefone1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTelefone);
        nome1.setText(nomeant);
        telefone1.setText(foneant);
    }

    AdicionarContato();
    ResetarInfo();      
}
```

And the code of the button "Salvar" when clicked:

```
  public void AdicionarContato() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       final EditText nm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNome);
       final EditText tlf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTelefone);


    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSalvarContato);
    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final String nome = nm.getText().toString();
            final String telefone = tlf.getText().toString();
            if(nome.length() != 0 && telefone.length() != 0){
                if(mIndex.equals("")) {                 
                    ContentValues valor = new ContentValues();
                    valor.put("nome", nome);
                    valor.put("telefone", telefone);
                    db.insert("contatos", null, valor);
                    ShowMessage("Sucesso","O Contato " + nome + " foi salvo com sucesso");
                }
                else {
                    String[] whereArgs = {"nome", "telefone"};

                    ContentValues dataToInsert = new ContentValues();                          
                    dataToInsert.put("nome", nome);
                    dataToInsert.put("telefone", telefone);

                    db.update("contatos", dataToInsert, "nome='"+nomeant+" and telefone='"+foneant+"'", whereArgs);
                    ShowMessage("Sucesso","O Contato " + nome + " foi salvo com sucesso");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The LogCat error it shows that:
`Failure 1 (table contatos already exists) on 0x2205b0 when preparing 'create table contatos(nome varchar(50),telefone varchar(20))'.`

My POV: the result in the LogCat says that the table already exists but, in the code i cant see where i shows that im trying to create it, wrong, i try to connect to it and not create it.

Comment: It appears that you're trying to recreate a table that already exists. My knowledge of `SQLite` is limited but after a quick search look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293826/problem-with-sqlite-oncreate-in-android , also you have the sqlite keywords `IF NOT EXISTS` to append to the `CREATE TABLE` sql string: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contatos...`. Also it would be helpful to know how you create/populate the sqlite database.

Comment: by my main.java when onCreate but i know its created and populated alright because i had only the "Add Contact" but now the Alter contact and if you read the code will show that if the EditTexts values is blank it will ADD a new contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the whereArgs here since you are attaching the arguments in the where clause itself. Just supply null to in place of whereArgs -

```
db.update("contatos", dataToInsert, "nome='"+nomeant+"' and telefone='"+foneant+"'", null);
```

But it is always better to use the arguments. It prevents sql injection and also takes care of escaping special characters. In your case -

```
db.update("contatos", dataToInsert, "nome=? and telefone=?", whereArgs);
```

Also, your whereArgs is wrong. It should be -

```
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {nomeant, foneant};
```

[FONT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606951/database-update-crashing-app) from the user `Mukesh Soni`.

Answer (score 0):

Also using the whereArgs allows for some SQLite optimizations,
another issue in your code is that you dont check for the return values of update and insert operations

```
db.update("contatos", dataToInsert, "nome='"+nomeant+"' and telefone='"+foneant+"'", null);
```

```
db.insert("contatos", null, valor);
```

ocurrs you have a success in your operation you should check for the returned values of update
and insert to check if the operations actually have had success.

You should also check [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) good tutorial on SQLite on Android as a good starting point.